# Using Ajax to stay on the same page upon submiting form not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

Im trying to create a form that when you submit the form,you stay on the same page and sends the user inputs to Process.php and to my database. The problem that I'm facing is that the page either refreshes or opens up the page Process.php

**My Form**

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" class="copy" id="formid" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Project name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>


        Video: 
        <input type="text" rows="1" cols="40" name="video">
    <br> 
    Svar 1<input type="text" name="answer1"/> 
    <select name="point1">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Svar 2<input type="text" name="answer2"/> 
    <select name="point2">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Svar 3<input type="text" name="answer3"/> 
    <select name="point3">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Svar 4<input type="text" name="answer4"/> 
    <select name="point4">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <br>



       <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="create question" id="submit">
    </form>
```

**Process.php**

```
<?php
// Exempel 1: Lägga till 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$connect = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password)or 
die("Kunde inte koppla");

mysqli_select_db($connect, 'wildfire');


$name=$_POST['name'];
$video=$_POST['video'];
$answer1=$_POST['answer1'];
$answer2=$_POST['answer2'];
$answer3=$_POST['answer3'];
$answer4=$_POST['answer4'];

$point1=$_POST['point1'];
$point2=$_POST['point2'];
$point3=$_POST['point3'];
$point4=$_POST['point4'];




$sql1= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point) VALUES ('$answer1', '$point1')";

$result=$connect->query($sql1);

$sql2= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point) VALUES ('$answer2', '$point2')";

$result=$connect->query($sql2);

$sql3= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point) VALUES ('$answer3', '$point3')";

$result=$connect->query($sql3);

$sql4= "INSERT INTO question (answer, point) VALUES ('$answer4', '$point4')";

$result=$connect->query($sql4);

print $sql1;
print $sql2;
print $sql3;
print $sql4;

}


?>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });

      });
```

Comment: is there a form somewhere in your html?

Comment: BTW you have a lot of dangerous queries that lead to a painfull sql injection

Comment: do you get that alert message?

Comment: @JulioSoares check my edit, there is a form under "my form" section

Comment: What is the required of action="process.php"  and you are doing it in ajax,so please remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will fix the issue (copied answer from [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631165/event-preventdefault-not-working-when-submiting-form?rq=1), with credits to @HarveyARamer):

> My best guess is that you are adding your `form` submit listener
>   before the form is actually rendered. Try wrapping your jQuery in
>   `$(document).ready(function () {})`;

Answer (score 0):

probably you gave action to your form. If you provide action to your form it will open the page which you specified in your action. Try remove action attribute of form If you gave

Answer (score 0):

try prevent default after your ajax success instead of before starting ajax

```
$(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });

    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

Use type as button instead of submit

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="create question" id="submit">
```

**Javascript**

On Click function use this below function

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){

     e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });
```